# Best way to Query Records

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having trouble with the performance of my rails application. This might be the effect of a  poor database structure. And the page is frequently viewed by users, considering that the record is 5k+.

```
Current System:

Model: 
person has_many payment

Controller:
@total_payments = 0
person.each do |p|
  @total_payments += p.payments.map(&:value).sum
end

View:
@total_payments
```

- Is it better to have a separate database for a counter than to search and count through the records?
- what databse structure do you recommend/ advice?

Comment: What is `person.each`? I guess it should be `persons.each`? Besides this is payments controller?

Comment: Try using `mini-profiler` in your database to see how things are accessing your database. You could also do a `Rails.cache.fetch` and `memcache` or `dahli|memcache` the payment sums. This will increase your memory, but deliver a faster experience.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try mini-profiler then do a memcache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `persons` is an Activerecord relation

```
persons.joins(:payments).sum(:value)
```

If `persons` is an array already (less preferred)

```
Payment.where(:person_id => persons.map(&:id)).sum(:value)
```

If total payment is the only attribute need from associated payments in this view. Then the fastest method would be to make `total_payments` a field in `person` table. Update it whenever an associated `payment` is made. Something similar to counter cache. Then you won't need to make a sql query for payments at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like Payment.select('value') as a base query so that you are only doing one query and mapping over that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try

`@total_payments += p.payments.pluck(:value).sum`

This will only select the `value` from each payment instead of all fields in the table. Are your tables indexed on the `person_id` in the `Payment` table? This would also help speed up the database.

(on mobile atm so cannot dive much deeper)